# flash messages wont appear in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing some flash messages for my app but when i redirect to the main page they wont apear...

i have my index like this

```
def index
end
```

and i have the method that makes the flash message when the form makes a request like this:

```
def request
   flash[:notice] = in_words(params[:number].to_i) 
   redirect_to root_path 
end
```

my app layout.html.erb looks like this:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
        <%= flash[:notice] %>  
    </div>
<% end %>
```

im looking at the terminal and it does several jumps and i think thats why the flash messages wont keep but i already tried something i found here that was about writing in the application controller this:

```
alias :std_redirect_to :redirect_to
def redirect_to(*args)
   flash.keep
   std_redirect_to *args
end
```

but they still wont apear, its just a simple message what am i doing wrong? 
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried `redirect_to root_path, notice: in_words(params[:number].to_i)`?

Comment: actualy yes! it didnt worked too, i managed to do what i want withajax but that wasnt the point :C

Comment: In a standard rails app, that alias of `redirect_to` should not be necessary. You are visiting your `request` action (not your `index` action) when looking for the flash message, correct? If so, is it possible that your `layout.html.erb` template is not being used (`application.html.erb` is the default on a unmodified rails app)?

Comment: you may be right, actually my root is pointed to index.html.erb from my main controller and i have the request but i tend to redirect to root again after the request is done